# コミット リスト プラグインがインストールできない

Tags: emeditor

EmEditorのインストール時に「コンテキスト メニュー」を外した場合、コミット リスト プラグインがインストールされません。
プラグインの設定から手動で追加しようとすると「指定されたモジュールが見つかりません」とエラーが出ます。
コミット リスト プラグインはエクスプローラ拡張機能に依存しているという仕様なのでしょうか？

一応、ユーザー別インストールを行ったうえでコンフィグからコンテキスト メニューの設定を外せばコミット リストも動作するようですが、できれば不要な機能をインストールするのは避けたいのですが……

EmEditor version 21.8.0、21.9 beta1 / Windows10 21H1(64bit)

Comment: 今後、不具合の報告の場合には、お問い合わせ https://jp.emeditor.com/support/#contact からご連絡ください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

いつもお世話になっております。江村です。

これは v21.8.902 で修正します。ご報告ありがとうございます。